# f.hidden_field in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am trying to insert a user id from devise into another table which collects contact details and company name and so on and i am using -

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
```

and all i seem to get back is an error on the page when i load it up -

```
undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum
```

Extracted source (around line #46):

am i missing something, do I have to put anything in the controller so i can access the current_user information?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Robbie

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use it like

```
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

or

```
   <%= hidden_field_tag "user_id",nil,:value => current_user.id %>
```

Try it..

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this.

`<%= hidden_field_tag('some_object[user_id]', current_user.id)%>`